# Deploying Python application+dependencies on OSX from Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, deployment, py2app

**Background:**
I'm writing a non-commercial application in Python, that uses wxPython, and depends on  pyPortMidi and SciPy (both available on PyPi). I would like to share this with a small circle of Mac users - who live in different countries.

I work on Ubuntu, and don't have access to OSX systems for testing.

**What I'm looking for:**
A end-user friendly means of deploying my application, especially given the dependencies

**What I've found so far:**

- Like Ubuntu, OSX comes with it's own Python bundled
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379032/deploying-python-app-to-mac-and-windows-users)
  suggests py2app. However, it's not clear from the
  [documentation](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)
  whether I can build an OSX app on an Ubuntu platform. Ditto with cx-Freeze.

**Specific Questions:**

1. Can I use py2app to build an OSX app on Ubuntu? And will it automagically include the above dependencies, or do I need to specify it somehow?
2. If not, can I write some sort of OSX script that will install the package dependies (using easy install, perhaps), painlessly on the end-user system? I haven't used distutils before, and I'm unfamiliar with OSX scripting, so any pointers would be appreciated!

Apologies for the noob questions, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [py2exe](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://www.py2exe.org/&q=&esrc=s&ei=0f3xUeOgAoa08QSRsID4AQ&usg=AFQjCNF_T1hVnVMhG8dqO70LKjVOLvWhUQ) for Windows

[Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) on Linux and as you say `py2app` for Mac

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't answer my specific questions at all. I wasn't asking about Windows and Linux, and I've already mentioned py2app, so I don't quite get the utility of this answer. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: e.e, You can build the App with `Freeze` this will add the dependencies, and sometimes the app works on Mac

Answer (score 0):

[py2app doesn't work on non-mac machines](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2010-October/022715.html). As suggested by @victor-castillo-torres, have a look at `Freeze`, as also suggested in the linked mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Py2app only works on OSX systems, the code does not support building
   bundles for other platforms than the one it is running on.  That
   is, py2app uses the currently running python installation to build a
   depedency graph and copies the files mentioned in that graph to the
   application bundle.
2. From the point of view of building script to install the dependencies
   for your script OSX is just like any other Unix system, but with
   different GUI libraries. A script that uses easy_install to install 
   dependencies could be made to work, although I don't know if all your
   dependencies are easily available that way (in particular wxPython).