# How would I distribute python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

Im working on a python project of mine and i wanted it to be able to run like a application. so i made a gui for it and i want to distribute it for other people to use. but i used packages like requests and tkinter. how would i make the program more portable? so people could just click on the .py file and my gui would just come up.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# imports
import requests
import time
from tkinter import *
import random

# variables
test = 'https://api.nicehash.com/api?method=stats.provider.ex&addr=37sCnRwMW7w8V7Y4zyVZD5uCmc9N1kZ2Q8&callback=jQuery111304118770088094035_1506738346881&_=1506738346882'
url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?'



# def function to update
def update_bitcoin_ui():

    # update the data sourced form the website
    req = requests.get(url)
    data = req.json()
    bit = (data['data'][0]['amount'])

    # update the gui to reflect new value
    thelabel.config(text = "1 BTC = %s USD" % bit)

    # verify the Ui is updating
    #thelabel.config(text=str(random.random()))
    root.after(1000, update_bitcoin_ui)

# gui workspace
root = Tk()
thelabel = Label(root, text = "")

# set more of the gui and launch the ui
thelabel.pack()
root.after(1000, update_bitcoin_ui)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: i found what i was looking for. i was looking for something to the effects of pyinstaller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying python app to Mac and Windows users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379032/deploying-python-app-to-mac-and-windows-users) and [deploying python applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9421373/62576)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a few ways.

Use something like [GitHub](https://GitHub.com). Register then create a repository. Users can the go to your repository (`https://GitHub.com/username/repo_name`) and download it through their browsers. Alternatively, *nix users can do `git clone https://GitHub.con/username/repo_name`.

Or, upload your script to PyPi. You can then do `pip install [package name]` on Windows/*nix, and dependencies will automatically be installed. Read how to do so [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#setup-py).

If you're simply looking for an easy way to install dependencies:

You could use requirements.txt, which is a text file with all of your dependencies. The user can then do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and all of your dependencies will be installed.

Or, you could create a `setup.py`. It would have information such as your dependencies, author ect. The user can then install it with `python setup.py install`.

Finally, you could simply make a try/except statement like this:

```
import pip
try:
    import module
except:
    pip.main(['install', 'module'])
```

BUT WAIT! Maybe your user doesn't have Python. Nobody wants to install all that just for a few uses. In that case, you can check out Py2Exe.

Comment: I think OP is not asking the means to distribute the code, but to make it portable so that users don't have to install dependencies.